# What information can I extract from an overlap of two personal probability distributions?

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian

Inspiration: https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/trees-stars-milky-way/

Let's say I take a Bayesian approach and use probability distributions to represent my beliefs about the number of stars in the Milky Way and the number of trees on Earth, as shown below:

[image]

The overlapping area is approximately 0.25.

Let's say I am interested in evaluating my beliefs regarding the following proposition: There are more trees on Earth than stars in the Milky Way.

I want to assign a probability to this proposition to represent my degree of belief that the proposition is true.

**Based on the distributions I shared previously, would assigning a probability of 0.75 be correct [ p(proposition is true) = 0.75 ]?**

Do I need to do some form of a Bayesian comparison of means, a t-test, or something else instead?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio of two gamma-distributed RVs is the [generalized beta prime distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution#Generalization). The CDF can be defined in terms of the ordinary hypergeometric function, ${}_2F_1$:

$F(x;\alpha,\beta,q)=\frac{(xq)^{\alpha}{}_2F_1(\alpha,\alpha+\beta,\alpha+1,-yq)}{\alpha\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)}$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the shape parameters of the two gammas, and $q$ is the ratio of the rate parameters of the two gammas.

Evaluating the CDF at $x=1$ will give the probability that a RV from the second gamma will be greater than a RV from the first gamma. In R:

```
library(hypergeo)
f <- function(x, a, b, q) (x*q)^a*Re(hypergeo(a, a + b, a + 1, -x*q))/a/beta(a, b)
f(1, 2.5, 2.5, 0.00568/0.00125)
#> [1] 0.9389194
```

Check the answer against a simulation.

```
set.seed(697621918)
trees <- rgamma(1e7, 2.5, 0.00125)
stars <- rgamma(1e7, 2.5, 0.00568)
mean(trees > stars)
#> [1] 0.9387685
```